# Getting element number or setting an identifier for it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that gets modified dynamically in HTML. Like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>Some value<li>
  <li>another</li>
  <li>more</li>
  <li>more<li>
  <li>more</li>
</ol>
```

What I want to do, is that when a user clicks on a certain element in that list, I want to call a function and pass a numeric argument that would represent the offset of that `<li>` relative to the parent `<ol>`.

How should I do this?

I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of `on()` (for binding minimum event handlers and to handle the dynamic updating that you mentioned) and the `index()` method to determine the element's index relative to its parent.

```
$("ol").on("click", "li", function() {
    yourFunction($(this).index());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cHCB/).

---

If you didn't have jQuery...

```
var ol = document.querySelector("ol");
var olLi = ol.querySelectorAll("li");
var handleClick = function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var index = 0;

    while (target = target.previousElementSibling) {
        index++;   
    }

    yourFunction(index);

};

ol.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr7te/).

---

If you had to support old browsers without jQuery...

```
var ol = document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];
var olLi = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
var handleClick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var index = 0;

    while (target = target.previousSibling) {
        (target.nodeType == 1) && (index++);   
    }

    yourFunction(index);

};

ol.addEventListener && ol.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
ol.attachEvent && ol.attachEvent("onclick", handleClick);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4qbt/).

Comment: Oh well, that was fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .index() for this.

```
var selectedIndex = $("#yourID").index() + 1;
```

Here is [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pervez/8cHCB/1/) for index start from 1

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wanted their index 1 based.

Comment: It does, but the OP didn't mention that as a requirement.